# Why can't I read these dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I'm having trouble with reading several dataframes. I have this function

```
def readDF(hdfsPath:String, more arguments): DataFrame = {//function goes here}
```

it takes an hdfs path for a partition and returns a dataframe (it basically uses `spark.read.parquet` but I have to use it). I'm trying to read several of them by using `show partitions` in the following fashion:

```
val dfs = spark.sql("show partitions table")
.where(col("partition").contains(someFilterCriteria))
.map(partition => {
  val hdfsPath = s"hdfs/path/to/table/$partition"
  readDF(hdfsPath)
}).reduce(_.union(_))
```

but it gives me this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 12 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 12.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 44, csmlcsworki0021.unix.aacc.corp, executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I think it's because I'm doing `spark.read.parquet` inside a `map` operation for a dataframe, because if I change my code for this one

```
val dfs = spark.sql("show partitions table")
.where(col("partition").contains(someFilterCriteria))
.map(row=> row.getString(0))
.collect
.toSeq
.map(partition => {
  val hdfsPath = s"hdfs/path/to/table/$partition"
  readDF(hdfsPath)
}).reduce(_.union(_))
```

it loads the data correctly. However, I don't want to use `collect` if possible. How can achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readDF is creating a data frame from parquet files in HDFS. It must be executed on driver side. The first version, in which you execute using a map function over the rows of the original dataframe, suggest you're trying to create a DF in the executors, and this is not feasible.

Comment: So this means I can't do this without collecting the list?

Comment: correct. If I understand your question right, you have a table containing locations of other tables you'd like to read. So you must collect these locations in order to create dataframes for them